# How can we avoid the TransmitException when writing to the channel

Tags: xbee

We are using XU-A11 X-STICK 2.4GHZ USB TO XBEE and XU3-A11 XBEE3 USB ADAPTER sticks. And the xbee-java library version 1.3.0

We created a test where we send the same data every 100ms. We see that we get the TransmitException about once a minute.
Detail of the exception: "There was a problem transmitting the XBee API packet. > Error: No acknowledgement received (0x01)"

Is there a way to avoid getting this exception?

Code snippet:

```
while (true) {
  localDevice.sendData(xBee64BitAddress, data);
  Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Config:

```
serialPort = /dev/ttyUSB0
baudRate = 9600
dataBits = 8
stopBits = 1
serialParityConfiguration = NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're sending 10 packets/second at 9600 baud, so you're data (with overhead) needs to be 96 bytes or less (9600 bits/sec is about 960 bytes/sec).  Try increasing your baud rate for a start.

It might not be possible to avoid the exception entirely.  What if the other device is offline or rebooting?  Write an exception handler to log the error, and then act on that error as appropriate.  Maybe having one error each second is acceptable, but if there's a sequence of more than 4 errors you want to do something about it.

Comment: If we set the timeout on 5 seconds then we also get the same exception.

Comment: How's your signal quality?  What is the distance between modules?  If you modules have antenna connectors, are you remembering to connect antennas?

Comment: There is about 1 meter between the modules.

Comment: Does the remote device receive the data?  How about antennas -- are these modules with a chip antenna, or a connector that expects to have an antenna attached?  If close together, the modules can work without an antenna, but would probably experience dropped packets.  If you can connect to a computer running XCTU, you can run a range test and measure signal quality.  https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001456-13/concepts/c_range_test.htm

Comment: At the moment we do not have the time to do the proper tests, as soon as we get the time I will let you know what the results are. We are not using antennas.

Comment: If you aren't using antennas, make sure you're purchasing modules with an integrated antenna.  If there's a small connector for an antenna on the board, you should be connecting an antenna to it for it to work correctly.